# If $\alpha I < A < \beta I$, is it true that $\alpha^2 I < A^2 < \beta^2 I$ where $A$ is symmetric and $\alpha, \beta >0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If $\alpha I < A < \beta I$, is it true that $$\alpha^2 I < A^2 < \beta^2 I$$ where $A$ is symmetric and $\alpha, \beta >0$. Here $A<B$ means that $B-A$ is positive definite.

In general, if for symmetric positive definite matrices $A, B, C$ with $B < A < C$, for what condition on $K$, does it hold:
$$B^k < A^K < C^K$$

Comment: Here, $A< B$ means that $B-A$ is positive definite.

Comment: a sufficient condition is mutual commutativity of A, B, and C

Comment: @user8675309, would you mind telling why mutual commutativity is a sufficient condition?

Comment: @n15 they are mutually orthogonality diagonalizable (i.e. you can effect a congruence transform, which preserves the inequality $B\lt A$, using orthogonal matrices which means it is also a similarity transform) so that reduces it to comparing diagonal matrices and of course the map $x\mapsto x^k$ is strictly increasing for $x\gt 0$

Answer (score 2):

Remark that $A^{2}-\alpha ^{2}I=(A-\alpha I)(A+\alpha I)$ ,Now both $(A-\alpha I);(A+\alpha I)$ are positive definite and they commute so their product is also positive,this proves that $\alpha ^{2}I < A^{2}$.Of course u can prove the other inequality in the same way.I'am not aware of the general case, but if one is willing to use the same approach, then a sufficiet condition for the inequality $A^{k}<B^{k}<C^{k}$ to hold for every $k$ is that both $A,C$ commute with $B$;($B^{k}-A^{k}=(B-A)(B^{k-1}+B^{k-2}A+\cdots $)